# Passing variables between QGIS plugin and a combobox in layers custom form?

Tags: pyqgis

I am developing a plugin that asks the user to enter in "**lineEdit**" boxes, names of population types, depending on the number of types that they have previously defined.

Once these names are validated on the plugin, I want to be able to display them in a combobox within the form of the layer that was previously created by the plugin.

Basically, I want my plugin to be able to store its values and display them in a list within the form.

I have the code of my plugin in a file **Chargementdialog.py** and the initialization code of my form in **shapefile_form_code.py**.

Here is a part of the code I use in my plugin, in case the user chooses two types of Population:

```
class DeuxTypesPop(QtGui.QDialog): 
  def __init__(self): 
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self) 
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog_Deux_Types_Population() 
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
  
    self.ui.NamePop2_2.editingFinished.connect(self.store)

  def store(self):
    settings=QSettings()
    settings.setValue("/Nom_du_Plugin/config/Nb_Types_Population/Two/LPCD_One", self.ui.LPCDPop1_2.value())
    settings.setValue("/Nom_du_Plugin/config/Nb_Types_Population/Two/Name_One", self.ui.NamePop1_2.text())
    settings.setValue("/Nom_du_Plugin/config/Nb_Types_Population/Two/LPCD_Two", self.ui.LPCDPop2_2.value())
    settings.setValue("/Nom_du_Plugin/config/Nb_Types_Population/Two/Name_Two", self.ui.NamePop2_2.text())
```

And here is part of the code I used for the custom form

```
def shapefile_form_code(dialog,layerdid,featureid):
  global myDialog
  myDialog=dialog

  settings=QSettings()

  global PopType11
  PopType11=settings.value("/Nom_du_Plugin/config/Nb_Types_Population/One/Name", type=str)
  global PopType12
  PopType12=settings.value("/Nom_du_Plugin/config/Nb_Types_Population/Two/Name_One", type=str)
  global PopType22
  PopType22=settings.value("/Nom_du_Plugin/config/Nb_Types_Population/Two/Name_Two", type=str)   

  
  global TypedePop
  TypedePop=dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"TypedePop")
  TypedePop.clear()
  NbTypePop=settings.value("/Nom_du_Plugin/config/Nb_Type_Population",type=int)


  settings.sync()

  global MyList
  
  if NbTypePop<7 and NbTypePop>0:
    if NbTypePop == 1:
      MyList=PopType11
      TypedePop.addItem(MyList)

    elif NbTypePop == 2:
      MyList=[]
      MyList.append(PopType12)
      MyList.append(PopType22)
      TypedePop.addItems(MyList)
```

When I put values in `PopType12`, `PopType22`, etc, instead of the settings.value... , the combobox gets updated, whereas by using this code, nothing happens, the combobox in the form stays empty.

I am new at Python and QGIS.

Comment: Add sample code to help you better!